# UIProgressView Progress Not Working for a local audio file Using AVAudio Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, progress, uiprogressview

My ProgressView doesn't update the progress.
I Did this by Interface Builder.
My ProgressView is in a `tableViewCell`.

```
//Declared in TableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressview;
```

and also Synthesized in Cell implementation.

then imported in my `viewController`

```
 //Declared AVAudioPlayer
 AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method :

```
obj.progressview.progress = 0.0;
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(methodToUpdateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
```

For every 1 second my methodToUpdateProgress is Called

```
-(void)methodToUpdateProgress{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [obj.progressview setProgress:(float)(player.currentTime/player.duration) animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"method");
    });
}
```

I have a button with 2 actions Play and Pause.
Those 2 actions works completely fine.

If I click on a Row in `tableview`, corresponding song plays, timer starts and for every 1 sec it called my methodToUpdateProgress,but my ProgressView doesn't show any progress.

Help me what should I do ?

Comment: Are you sure the progress bar outlet was properly connected in Interface Builder?  Does the NSLog run?

Comment: Yes , its connected properly and NSLog(@"method"); is printing every 1 sec.

Comment: what does `updateTime` method does in m_timer?

Comment: updateTime will change the button icon to play after every song played.

Comment: what you are doing in `updateTime:` ? and how you are referring `obj` in `cellForRowAtIndexpath ` and `methodToUpdateProgress ` ?

Comment: my ProgresView is in TableViewCell Class so i Cerated a Object as obj for my TableViewCell.thats why Im referring every time with obj.

TableViewCell *obj=[songTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];